# How to execute and display an included file in another line or later in the code

Tags: php, include, try-catch

This is the following code:

```
try {
                include $viewPath;
            } catch (Throwable $e) {
                $this->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } // call include later

            include __DIR__ . "/../Views/header.php";

            include __DIR__."/../Views/footer.php";
```

As can be seen the files are executed as follows, first a try function is used on the viewpath file. If any exceptions are caught they are then displayed on errorBox.php, which is included in my header.php. Header.php is executed showing the header of the page and the error, afterwards footer.php is executed.

What I want to achieve: I would like that the included viewPath is somehow displayed after header.php. The code has to stay the same, however the execution should be done after header.php is executed. The try, catch part should however stay there. I hope I was clear enough, sorry if I made any mistakes!

Comment: `the execution should be done after header.php is executed`...that's possible, but then there won't be any errors available to show in the header.php, because they won't have happened yet. So you'd have to find another way of showing any errors which occur during execution of the $viewpath file.

Comment: `The code has to stay the same, however`...you can't change the functionality and order of execution without changing the code. This is a contradictory requirement.

Comment: `I would like that the included viewPath is somehow displayed after header.php`...if you actually just want to change when the output is _displayed_ (rather than executed), that's different. Obviously we don't know what the code in the $viewpath file does, but if you change it so contains a function which returns a string instead of directly echoing the content, then you can include the file, then call the function and assign the output to a variable. Then you can echo the variable whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use output buffering to save the contents and then print them where you want

```
try {
    ob_start();
    include $viewPath;
    $file_content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    } 
    catch (Throwable $e) {
        ob_end_clean();
        $this->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
    }

include __DIR__ . "/../Views/header.php";
echo $file_content;
include __DIR__."/../Views/footer.php";
```

Comment: Managed to do it beforehand, but the way you did is way more cleaner. The function I needed was the ob_start() or other ob functions. Very nice tool! Thankyou!!